# Convert Bitmap Image Object to Bitmap in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS Word document which has Bitmap Image Objects. When I look at it in Word are gray boxes.

[image]

It looks like I can convert them to bitmaps manually by right clicking the image object.

[image]

Does anyone know why the objects are gray until convert? Also I was trying to write a VBA script to automatically convert all the image objects, but I wasn't quite sure how to do that. I tried recording a macro but when you're recording it doesn't allow you to right click the object and I couldn't find the option in the toolbar/ribbon.

If anyone knows where this option is located in the ribbon so that I can record the macro, or know how to write this macro, it would be greatly appreciated!